# playing a randomly selected piece of audio from an array, cant figure out where I went wrong

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, random, adobe

the code is as follows:

```
var audio1 = new Audio("sounds/sleighride.mp3");

var audio2 = new Audio("sounds/letitsnow.mp3");


var audio3 = new Audio("sounds/comingtotown.mp3");

var array = ["audio1", "audio2", "audio3"]


function soundrandom (){ 
    var songrandom = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)]; 
    songrandom.play();
}

soundrandom();
```

the answer may be obvious but has had me stumped for a bit, error is "soundrandom.play(); is not a function".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are objects not strings.

```
var array = [audio1, audio2, audio3]
```

To make it easier to edit later you could always do this:

```
var audioArr = [
  new Audio("sounds/sleighride.mp3"),
  new Audio("sounds/letitsnow.mp3"),
  new Audio("sounds/comingtotown.mp3")
]
```

Comment: how would I adapt the same code setup but using movieclips, tried swapping the new Audio(".....") to new lib.example but alas didn't work

Comment: var video = document.createElement('video'); There is no new Video() constructor like there is for Audio.

Comment: thank you for the answer but sorry i meant a symbol which is a movieclip (as in button or graphic) in adobe animate. my fault for lack of clarity.

Comment: You would have to elaborate on what you mean. I don't know what lib.example even means in this context. Are you just talking about simple gifs?

Comment: its hard to explain, its a converted symbols (not a video) which symbol property/type is a Movie Clips. i am trying to play a random symbols/Movie Clips (like the previous code) out of the array. and i think one of my problems is the way i'm trying to declare it but not sure. this in adobe animate, not sure if you understood that, but if you don't thanks for all your help.